# Call a stored procedure for every select result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an stored procedure to delete from a long series of tables. It uses one main ID as parameter. I have to delete a bunch of rows based on a view that show that lot of tables. I want to apply the deleting procedure to every filtered result from that view. Some thing like:

```
SELECT id FROM view WHERE another_id=100;
```

And then apply the stored procedure to those results like:

```
CALL deleteProcedure(id);
```

Comment: Where is the "series of tables"?  What is a "registry"?  What is in the VIEW?  Are you asking how to use a CURSOR?

Comment: @RickJames I have a table related to like 6 other tables, and some of them have relations to other tables. I made an stored view to show all the results in one single query. By registry i meant row. The view returns a _primary key_; which i want to send as a parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: So, the Stored Procedure needs to be 6 (or more) `DELETE` statements using `id`?

Comment: @RickJames I have already created the stored procedure and it works. But i have to call it for like 150+ rows. I want it to bee called automaticaly. Something like 
`CALL deleteProcedure(SELECT id FROM view WHERE another_id=100 )`

Comment: Why doesn't the stored procedure take the another_id as a parameter? Then it could delete based on a join or subquery instead of performing deletes one ID at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another Stored Procedure.  In it, `DECLARE` a `CURSOR` for `SELECT id FROM view WHERE another_id=100;`.  Create a loop; in the loop `FETCH` one id, then `CALL deleteProcedure(id);`.  (See the manual and online examples for the details.)